# Create a script to collect files from yesterday

Tags: command-line, cmd, batch-processing, ibm-sterling

I'm working in Sterling B2B Integrator and I have to create a Business Process to collect only the files from "yesterday" (the previous date) The problem is that B2Bi doesn't have a service to do that and the colection directory has over than 7000 files, so I can't use a GetDocInfo service to collect the dates into tags because the Sterling may colapse.

So, I decided to use the Command Line Adapter to invoke a script that would do that for me. The problem is that the script doesn't work either:

```
set var1=%1       /* UNC File Path */

set var2=%2       /* Source directory */

set var3=%3       /* "yesterday" date */

set var4=%4       /* save the list of files into a .txt*/

set var5=%5       /* copy the files from yesterday into this directory */

PUSHd **%var1%** & 
forfiles /p **%var2%** /s /C  " cmd /c echo @path @FDATE | findstr /m **%var3%**" > %var4% & 
for /f %%a in (**%var4%**) do copy %%a **%var5%** &
```

Function: The script should collect the files from yesterday and save them into a specific directory.

Example:

```
PUSHd "\\emea\e801\Public" & 
forfiles /p _AppData\CAMS\PDFS\Digital\CertificadoCancelado /s /C  " cmd /c echo @path @FDATE | findstr /m "27/07/17"" > _Shared\_AppData\MFT\BackupSterling\temp_puente_PRO\Lista_DIGCRT02\ficherosAyer.txt & 
for /f %%a in (_Shared\_AppData\MFT\BackupSterling\temp_puente_PRO\Lista_DIGCRT02\ficherosAyer.txt) do copy %%a _Shared\_AppData\MFT\BackupSterling\temp_puente_PRO\Lista_DIGCRT02\DIGCRT02 &
```

Why is this script not working?

Answer (score 0):

The script is not working because it is not syntactically correct. What are the asterisks doing around the variable names.

Here is a brief PowerShell script that is the core of what you need to do. It needs to have a Parms() block. When you are satisfied that it will copy the files correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Copy-Item` command.

Please note that this does not maintain the subdirectory structure from the `src_dir`. This will not work well if you have selected files with the same name in different subdirectories.

```
$src_dir = 'C:\src\t'       #var2
$the_date = '2017-07-21'    #var3
$log_file = 'C:\src\xxx'    #var4
$dest_dir = 'C:\src\xxx'    #var5

if (Test-Path $log_file) { Remove-Item $log_file }

Get-ChildItem -Path $src_dir -File -Recurse |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ((Get-Date $_.LastWriteTime -Format yyyy-MM-dd) -eq $the_date) { $_.FullName }
    } |
    Tee-Object -FilePath $log_file -Append |
    Copy-Item -Destination $dest_dir -WhatIf
```

If you -must- do this from a .bat script, put the script above into a filename with a `.ps1` extension such as `Move-FilesDated.ps1`. Then, call it from the .bat script.

```
powershell -NoProfile -File "Move-FilesDated.ps1"
```